# How do I find irregular values in columns in a data-frame that have a huge number of unique values?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, data-analysis, data-cleaning

Below is a sample of two columns in a [data-frame containing data about user-reviews for various Google Play Store apps](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/lava18/google-play-store-apps?select=googleplaystore.csv).

| Last Updated | current Version |
| --- | --- |
| January 7, 2018 | 1.0.0 |
| 1.0.19 | 1.2.1 |
| March 17, 2018 | Varies with device |

In these columns I want to find any anomalies/irregular values (such as '1.0.19' in the
column, 'Last Updated' and 'varies with device' in the column, 'current Version' as seen in the above table) during data cleaning. However, these columns respectively have 1378 and 2832 unique values. How do I scan through these values and find the anomalies in the quickest/most efficient way possible without having to go through each unique value in the huge list of values?

Comment: For date, you may have success by trying to parse it as date (using `pandas.to_datetime`) while giving a specific format (`%B%d%Y`). If this fails, pandas raises a `ParserError` which you can use to handle your exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')
def time_search(x):
    try:
        return pd.to_datetime(x)
    except:
        print("found extrange value:", x)
        return pd.NA

df['Last Updated'] = df['Last Updated'].apply(time_search)
```

output

```
found extrange value: 1.0.19
```

then should be easy to drop nan values for example

for the version column is easy to check if is valid or not

```py
df["Current Ver"].str.contains('^[0-9].([0-9].)*')
```

I sugest to explore this ideas for the rest of columns

Comment: Thank you. This worked. Do you have any solution for the current Version column as well?

Comment: I have added something for that column, try to play around with those ideas

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is concise and works correctly